# Minimum genus of torus necessary to embed complete graph $K_n$

Tags: topological-graph-theory

You can embed complete graphs $K_1$, $K_2$, $K_3$, and $K_4$ on a genus $0$ torus (a sphere). 
The minimal genus of a torus on which you can embed $K_5$, $K_6$, and $K_7$ is a $1$.
Then you need a torus of genus $2$ to embed ...

Is there a formula for any $K_n$, stating the minimum genus necessary to embed $K_n$ on a torus with that genus?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Found it. All I needed to search for was "genus of complete graphs" :

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphGenus.html

Ringel and Youngs 1968; Harary 1994, p. 118 :

$$\mbox{ceil}\left((n-3)(n-4)\over 12\right)$$

Please do edit the formula with MathJax.